# Kendo Grid - Group Expand collapse Events

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, expand

I have a grouped Kendo Grid and need to trap collapse and expand events. For grids with detail there is detailExpand event . Is there something equivalent for group expand/collapse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After poking around in the kendo source code, there is no directly provided event but you can just attach your own handler to the same event that kendo attaches to internally to handle the expand/collapse.

Internally, kendo attached a handler to expand/collapse icons like so:

```
if (that._isLocked()) {
    that.lockedTable.on(CLICK + NS, '.k-grouping-row .k-i-collapse, .k-grouping-row .k-i-expand', that._groupableClickHandler);
} else {
    that.table.on(CLICK + NS, '.k-grouping-row .k-i-collapse, .k-grouping-row .k-i-expand', that._groupableClickHandler);
}
```

where CLICK = "click" and NS = ".kendoGrid".

So, you can just add your own handler to the exact same element, i.e.:

```
var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
var table = grid._isLocked() ? grid.lockedTable : grid.table;

table.on('click.kendoGrid', '.k-grouping-row .k-i-collapse, .k-grouping-row .k-i-expand', myGroupableClickHandler);
```

and then do whatever you need to do in myGroupableClickHandler().

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/udUga